# How to put Bindings without jar(s) into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to put [this binding](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq) into eclipse if possible. I understand how to do it with .jar files, but this doesn't have a .jar file. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: "download ZIP" in right bottom corner for a start :)

Comment: I've got the zip and it's extracted, but I don't know what to do with it in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Download the source code. Install `Maven` if you don't have it already.

Run `mvn package` and it will be compile the source and package it into a jar inside `target` folder.

Comment: Thanks. That was really helpful. I'm close, but when I try to package it I get [this](http://gyazo.com/131c078f4695490787cc5cdc9255233b). It's probably something that's obvious, but I don't know.

Comment: you need to change directory to root folder where you have checked out the code. In other words, your working directory should be the folder where the checked out source code lies. Over there simply run `mvn package` ; you don't have to provide any arguments for e.g. `jzmq-master` to the command

Comment: Ok. Another step in the right direction. Now [this](http://gyazo.com/b564613261173b4aade0b4b0665469ae) happens.